# SQL query that can fetch records present in table 1 and not in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to write a query to fetch records in record table A and but not in  table B. As per my current application design, if a record is present in A then it should be present in table B as well. But due to some interfacing issues,  not all records of table A are present table B. Now I want to have all those records which are in A but not in B. How can I fetch those records? Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tableB b WHERE b.a_id = a.id
);
```

Comment: Awesome! it worked. But, in my scenario I'll need to check records like this:
if records is present in A1 or A2 or A3 but not in B1 and B2. How can I do so? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `UNION` in that case, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A1 UNION SELECT * FROM A2 ) a WHERE NOT EXISTS (*uion query for B tables*)`.